# Does a nested inner class automatically inherit from superclass of outer class in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes, superclass

Say I have an Outer class A and it's nested Inner Class B. A is subclass of C. Then is B also a subclass of C? Since B can access all private members of A and thus that(public and protected) of it's superclass, so I think B becomes a subclass of C.

Is my line of thinking right?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: No. Being a nested class in `A` does not amount to being a subclass of `A`'s superclass. Access to members is not the defining characteristic of being a subclass.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks for the answer, I'd appreciate if you could explain a little what's wrong in my line of thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you seem to be describing:

```
class C {} 
class A extends C {
    static class B {}
}
```

Being a nested class in `A` **does not** make `B` a subclass of `C`. Access to members is not the defining characteristic of being a subclass.

Suppose you try to assign an object of type `B` to a variable of type `C`.

```
C c1 = new A(); // OK -- A is a subclass of C
C c2 = new A.B(); // Not OK
```

If `B` were a subclass of `C`, the latter would be a legal assignment. But it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. If you want B to extend C, you may explicitly say:

```
class C {}

class A extends C {

    static class B extends C {
        //Todo...
    }
}
```

The nested class B is just a (static) member of A just like any other member of it. You can access public and protected or even package access methods and variables of C within B because A has inherited those members from C. Since B is a nested class of A, You can access (static) members of A which can be inherited from other class or not.